# Swift: UIButton not calling correctly

Tags: swift, uibutton

Here is my code (in Swift 2) creating my UI Button.

```
let SettingsBtn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
SettingsBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 40, height: 40)
SettingsBtn.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x * 1.8, y: view.center.y * 1.85)
SettingsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Gear"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
SettingsBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Settings"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(SettingsBtn)
```

In my function I have this:

```
PlayBtn.removeFromSuperview()
CharBtn.removeFromSuperview()
SettingsBtn.removeFromSuperview()
```

It removes everything but throws me an error when coming to `Settings.Btn`.

Not sure why, maybe because the way the UI Button is created? The code I for the button I found for creating a button with a custom image.

My error is below:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

Although I defined `var SettingsBtn : UIButton!` outside the class; My variable `SettingsBtn` is not highlighted like the rest of them.

Comment: Please post the error, your code seems fine.

Comment: Have you created SettingsBtn globally?

Comment: be sure to keep the reference to your SettingsBtn in order to make changes to that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that since I called it globally already, I could remove the let statement and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure from your code, but it seems to me that your SettingsBtn is going out of scope. Are you also sure that it's added to the view? I would try and placing a breakpoint on :

```
self.view?.addSubview(SettingsBtn)
```

and checking if the view can be unwrapped or if it's nil.

Perhaps you could post the rest of your code so we can get a clearer picture?

Comment: I could post the rest of my code, however there is something I noticed. My variable `SettingsBtn` is not highlighted like the rest of them